# drawable folder android

Tags: android, image

On my android project I have 5 kind ok drawable: xxhpdi, xhpid, hpdi, mpdi et lpdi

But I don't realy understand in witch file set my images

I had a look to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I need to class my pictures by size and by px/in

I have ic_launcher in my folders:

xxhpdi => 144*144px

xhpdi => 96*96px

hpdi => 72*72px

mpdi => 48*48px

lpdi => vide

But they are all in 72*72 px/in

I'd like to know how to set my pictures in res folders, why not just have a xxhpdi image ?
and did we always need to have 5 image, it weighed the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android system will choose the closest 'density bucket' (drawable folder) to the current device, and use that for some final resizing to the devices exact size.

Its a guideline to provide an image for every density bucket to ensure the best result, but in practice often an image will look just fine by only adding it in 1 or 2 folders.

If you have a problem with having some big images that make your app huge, cause you have to add them 5 times, you could try around with adding those only in 1 or 2 folders. 
Per example, xxhdpi is only nexus 10 at the moment, are you even really supporting that? ldpi is also not very common anymore. You could try adding it only in xhdpi, and scaling will probably look fine.

For the rest your images shouldn't be much more than some simple icons, which shouldn't take up a lot of space.

tl;dr: Yes if you want to follow guidelines for best result, but you can probably cut on app size without people actually noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Resolutions were explained in other answers. Regarding the question about weight of the app, You could provide different apks for different devices via Android Market, so particular apk would include only images for particular screen.
Moreover, the same time You don't need to do simultaneous development of many branches etc. just because of images differences, just follow [Android documentation on support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and produce separate builds using `aapt` `-c` key which would allow You to have only necessary configuration included in every build..

Answer (score 1):

Android comes different screen resolutions, each resolution depends on screen width/height.For mobiles you place the corresponding sized images in res folder. During run time device itself find the resolution and re size the resolution it needs. For some cases you may get issues like image squeeze etc. At these time you place the corresponding image sizes with their corresponding res folder with same names.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little toole for this.(BitmapCat) It scaled png-, bmp-, and jpg images for Android apps in:

- ldpi(low-density)
- mdpi(medium-density)
- hdpi(high-density)
- xhdpi(extra-high-density)
- xxhdpi(extra-extra-high-density)

Here you can download it: http://blog.axxg.de/bitmapcat-en/